# QueryingJSON PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE tableTestJSON (
    id serial primary key,
    data jsonb
);

INSERT INTO tableTestJSON (data) VALUES
('{}'),
('{"a": 1}'),
('{"a": 2, "b": ["c", "d"]}'),
('{"a": 1, "b": {"c": "d", "e": true}}'),
('{"b": 2}');
```

I can select the values. There is no problem this.

```
SELECT * FROM tableTestJSON;
```

I can test that two JSON objects are identical this query.

```
SELECT * FROM tableTestJSON WHERE data = '{"a":1}';
```

This query's output is :

id | data 
----+------
  1 | {"a": 1}
(1 row)

But i have a problem : 
Lets say I have a column:

```
{a: 30}
{a: 40}
{a: 50}
```

In this case, how can i query for all the elements containing a = 30 or a = 40. I was not able to find any solution for 'or', e.g.

```
select * from table where a in (10,20); // ??
```

or
How can I query on such condition?

Answer (score 1):

Extract a value of a json object using [the operator ->>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
select * 
from tabletestjson
where (data->>'a')::int in (1, 2)

 id |                 data                 
----+--------------------------------------
  2 | {"a": 1}
  3 | {"a": 2, "b": ["c", "d"]}
  4 | {"a": 1, "b": {"c": "d", "e": true}}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: In addition i test the another asnwer like this. 

Like this query: SELECT * FROM tableTestJSON WHERE data #> '{a}' IN ('10','20');

Thanks.